# Using iscan (GIMP plugin) from the command line

Tags: command-line, scanner, gimp

I'm something called `iscan` to use my scanner. However to use it, I need to go through a GUI to get my scanned pdf. When I run `iscan --help` (because just `iscan` launches the GUI), it tells me that it is a GIMP plugin and requires to have GIMP launched:

```
iscan is a GIMP plug-in and must be run by GIMP to be used
```

Is there a way to use GIMP plugins like this from the command line? I would MUCH rather run a simple command to output whatever is in my scanner to a pdf somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `scanimage` from sane-backends.